# Stop accepting characters once the user enters the exclamation sign

Tags: c++, stack

```
void main()
{
    Stack *S = new Stack;
    char val;

    while(true)
    {
        cout<<"enter character:"<<endl;
        cin>>val;
        S->push(val);
    }

    S->pop();
}
```

I am doing the Stacks data structure. what code do i write for it to stop accepting characters once the user enter the exclamation sign?

Comment: `if(val == '!') break;` after the `cin>> val;` perhaps?

Comment: omg i cant believe i forgot about that , gosh i must be really tired, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just break from the loop when an exclamation point is entered.

```
void main()
{
    Stack *S = new Stack;
    char val;

    while(true)
    {
        cout<<"enter character:"<<endl;
        cin>>val;
        if (val == '!') { // exclamation point was entered
             break;
        }
        S->push(val);
    }

    S->pop();
}
```